# How can I use fork in a recursive function?

Tags: c, unix, recursion, fork

I am trying to write a recursive program in order to build a process tree using fork. I think I build the tree correctly depending on the number of levels and the number of children. Howver, when I want to exit, I keep on building on the tree and I exceed the number of children and levels, and therefore I end up exiting uncorrectly.

Here is my code and a sample input and output. Please note that the number of children and number of levels needs to be specified in the command line arguments.

code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <errno.h>
int level;
static void run_process(const char *child, int lev)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "ALIVE: Level %d process with pid= %ld child of ppid=%ld\n",
           lev, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());
}

int fork_level (int l, int c){
int i;
pid_t rightchild;


 if (l>=level){

 fprintf(stderr, "Exiting: Level %d with pid= %ld, child of ppid= %ld\n",l,  (long)getpid(),    (long)getppid());
    exit (1) ;  
 }
 else {

    for (i=0; i<c; i++){
     if ((rightchild = fork()) < 0)
       {   
           fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
           return 0;
       }
       else if (rightchild == 0)
       {
           run_process("Right", l);
       fork_level (++l, c);   
       }
    }
    for (i=0; i<c; i++){
    wait (NULL);
     }
      fprintf(stderr, "Exiting: Level %d with pid= %ld, child of ppid= %ld\n",l,        (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());
 }
}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i, N=0, M=0, I=0, pflag=0, uflag =0; 
   char Nchar [3], Mchar [3], ichar [3];
 for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
   if (strcmp (argv[i], "-u")==0  ){
      uflag=1;

   }
   else if (strcmp (argv[i], "-N")==0){
       i++;
       strcpy (Nchar, argv[i]);
       N= atoi (Nchar);

   }
   else if (strcmp (argv[i], "-M")==0){
       i++;
       strcpy (Nchar, argv[i]);
       level= atoi (Nchar);

   }
   else if (strcmp (argv[i], "-p")==0){
       pflag=1;
   }
   else if (strcmp (argv[i], "-s")==0){
       i++;
       strcpy (ichar, argv[i]);
       I= atoi (ichar);

   }

 }
   if (uflag==1){
       printf ("u.....\n");
   }
  fork_level (0, N);

}
```

Here is how I run my code `./main -u -N 2 -M 2`
and here is the sample output:

```
    ALIVE: Level 0 process with pid= 26534 child of ppid=26533
ALIVE: Level 0 process with pid= 26535 child of ppid=26533
ALIVE: Level 1 process with pid= 26536 child of ppid=26534
ALIVE: Level 1 process with pid= 26538 child of ppid=26534
ALIVE: Level 1 process with pid= 26537 child of ppid=26535
Exiting: Level 2 with pid= 26536, child of ppid= 26534
Exiting: Level 2 with pid= 26538, child of ppid= 26534
Exiting: Level 2 with pid= 26537, child of ppid= 26535
ALIVE: Level 1 process with pid= 26539 child of ppid=26535
Exiting: Level 2 with pid= 26539, child of ppid= 26535
Exiting: Level 1 with pid= 26534, child of ppid= 26533
Exiting: Level 1 with pid= 26535, child of ppid= 26533
Exiting: Level 1 with pid= 26535, child of ppid= 26533
ALIVE: Level 1 process with pid= 26540 child of ppid=26534
Exiting: Level 2 with pid= 26540, child of ppid= 26534
Exiting: Level 1 with pid= 26534, child of ppid= 26533
Exiting: Level 0 with pid= 26533, child of ppid= 25113
```

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect. What output do you expect? Note that the alive/exiting messages are interleaved because your program runs in parallel.

Comment: In the sample output, I need to see only 'Exiting...' after creating the tree. However, there are some 'Alive...' in between, which means I create more children.

Comment: You aren't doing any synchronization here, so it's not like "creating the tree" is an atomic operation. Why would you expect every subprocess to wait until every other subprocess is created before any of them exit?

Comment: I just need to build the whole tree and then exit, just in case if the number of children or the number of levels gets bigger. I will be able to see the whe tree. Therefore I want all the alives successively and then all the exitings successively too

Comment: Then you'll need to arrange some IPC to coordinate when the processes are allowed to start exiting.  The simplest is probably `sleep(1);` before you do the exiting; no self-respecting modern computer will have problems forking all the children and getting all the alive messages out in less than a second (though it does depend on what else the computer is doing). It's odd that you have no level 2 processes that are alive, but you have a number of them exiting.  Your processes that do the waiting should really report on which child dies and the child's exit status; you're missing information.

Comment: I beleive that the tree  might be built up correctly, Can it be becaues of the misplacement of the print statements for the exiting?

Comment: If I had to create a tree of processes, I would exploit the recurrent nature of `fork()` and avoid writing a recursive function altogether.